# nestjs socket.io package uncompatibility

Tags: typescript, sockets, nestjs

I am trying to install follow documentation and work with socket.io on nestjs. But I am getting these issues when Installing packages. I tried various methods to update package , but nothing works!
any suggestions ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVMWE.png)

I tried installing the packages expecting everything to be ok since I followed documentations

Answer (score 0):

You have `@nestjs/core@9.4.3` installed. If you have `@nestjs/common@^10` installed you should install the matching `core` version (same major.minor.patch). This goes for `platform-socket.io` and `websockets` as well. They all need to be on the exact same version